# The use of “seem” in this sentence

Tags: verbs

So I just encountered this sentence:

> The writer must, however, be certain that the emphasis is warranted, lest a clipped sentence seem merely a blunder in syntax or in punctuation.

Why dose the author use “seem” instead of “seems”?

Answer (score 1):

A hypothetical, nonactual case is described (the clipped sentence appearing incorrect), so the [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) verb form is used, which is the bare form here.

Comment: Thanks Chemomechanics, that makes sense. So does “lest” always signal subjunctive mood?

Comment: Very often, yes; see [these example sentences](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/lest).